# Solve $ x (0\leq x<2\pi)$ for $\cos^2x - \sin x \cos x = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos^2x - \sin x \cos x = 1$ can be transformed into $\cos 2x - \sin 2x = 1$  (because $\cos 2x+1=2cos^2x$ and $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$)

Thus, i get $\cos(45-2x) = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

But i am confused, how to solve for $x$

By trial and error i get 0 and 180 , how do i know its all the posibillity

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that $\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x=1$, the equation reduces to
$$
\sin^2 x+\sin x \cos x = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sin x (\sin x + \cos x)=0
$$

Now, $\sin x $ is zero for $x = 0$, $x = \pi$ and $x = 2 \pi$. On the other hand, $sin x = -\cos x$ when $x = \frac 34 \pi$ and $x = \frac 74 \pi$. These are the solutions in the set $[0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: Thank you. If using my method, how do i solve it?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter check the answer by Wrench.

Answer (score 1):

We have $cos(\frac{\pi}{4}+2x)$=$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ from which it follows that $\frac{\pi}{4}+2x$=$\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi$ so we have $x=n\pi$ for some integer n or we can have $\frac{\pi}{4}+2x$=$\frac{7\pi}{4}+2n\pi$ and hence in this case we have $x$=$\frac{3\pi}{4}+n\pi$.

Remember $cos(A\pm B)$=$cos(A)cos(B)\mp sin(A)sin(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

After transformation the equation, we reduce it to 
$$\cos(2x)-\sin(2x) = 1$$
Then we apply the $\cos()$ expansion identity to further simplify it
$$\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
Say $a= 2x$ and $b= 45° = \frac{\pi}{4}$ Rad

$\cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot( \cos(2x)-\sin(2x) )$

$\cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Take $\arccos()$ of both sides, *notice my correction*

$2x+\frac{\pi}{4} = \arccos(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$

$2x+\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}$

$2x=0$ , $x = 0$

The other values of $x$ comes because of the periodic nature of $\cos()$, since we established that $\cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Then $\cos(2x+\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi{n}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$2x+2\pi{n} = 0$, $x+\pi{n} = 0$

$x \in ${$ 0 , -\pi , -2\pi, -3\pi , -4\pi, .......... $}$

Answer (score 0):

According to your  process, 
\begin{align} 
&\cos^2x - \sin x \cos x = 1 \\  
\implies &\cos2x-\sin 2x=1\\
\implies &\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {2}}\cos 2x- \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin 2x= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\implies&\cos (\dfrac{\pi}{4}+2x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}= \cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}\; \text{&}\;  \cos\dfrac{7\pi}{4},\text{since}\; x\in[0,2\pi]\\
\implies &(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+2x)= \dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{7\pi}{4}\\
\implies &x= 0, \;\dfrac{3\pi}{4}
 \end{align}